# Node Async and Request, Async not waiting and Request never send

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

So im completely stumped and hope someone can help with the combination of Node JS Async and Request modules. I'm attempting to build a list of file to download which I pass to Async, as an array of object contain all the information I need to download and store said file. After tons of debugging I discovered that Request are not even making there way out and I cant figure out why.

```
async.each(missingFiles,
    function (obj, cb) {

        console.log(obj.url);

        //var file = nfs.createWriteStream(obj.fullPath);
        request(obj.url, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(response)
          }

         cb();
       })
   },
   function (err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("Async failed");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok, so... what is making it to your console? Why isn't the request being sent? Without more information, this question is off topic.

Comment: The obj.url (item I want to request is making it to the screen), but nothing after that, it just moved on to the next obj.url. If i change the code to remove the if statement so I and just print any and all responses I get the same effect.

Comment: Is this block inside a http request handler? If yes, make sure you have the response returned after async tasks complete

Comment: @AwakeningByte im following the Request (https://github.com/request/request) docs for what I can tell and it doesn't appear that it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issues before. If you send response outside the async block, http request/response cycle ends before your async tasks complete. The fix is to have send response in the done() callback.

```
app.post("/download", function(req, res) {
  async.eachSeries(missingFiles, function (obj, cb) {
    ...
    //do your work here
    cb()
  }, function done() {
     res.json({success: true});
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried out your structure above, now only the first in the series urls are printed an still no data is returned.